# Objective C - OSX - forLoop giving inconsistent results

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to make a list of years based on their decade.

I have this forLoop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {

        NSString *thisYear = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", thisDecade];
        //NSLog (@"(long)selectedDecade++ %ld", (long)selectedDecade++ );
        thisDecade = thisDecade ++;
        NSLog (@"thisDecade %ld", thisDecade);
}
```

I use the result in a button label.
Logging the output shows a difference between the label text and the loop results and I have a sore neck trying to figure out why.. Is it something in the loop? thanks

Logs:

```
[AppDelegate setYears]
selectedDecade: 1970
thisDecade 1971

 RightSideBar aTitle is 1970
thisDecade 1972


 RightSideBar aTitle is 1971
 thisDecade 1973

 RightSideBar aTitle is 1972
 thisDecade 1974

 RightSideBar aTitle is 1973
 thisDecade 1975
```

UPDATE - I appreciate all the help, but I remain stumped. I'm attaching a screenshot of the logs, and the code that produces them.. Thanks again..

-(void)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString*)aTitle image:(NSImage*)image alternateImage:

```
(NSImage*)alternateImage
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    NSButtonCell * cell = [self addButton];
    [cell setTitle:aTitle];
    NSLog(@"RightSideBar aTitle is %@", aTitle); << see the logs vs the screenshot
    [cell setImage:image];
    [cell setAlternateImage:alternateImage];
}
```

logs:

[image]

[image]

UPDATE2: It turns out that I subclassed the custom cell incorrectly, and as a result, called it too many times..I will mark as complete as you all gave me great ideas to work with.I wish we could award multiple points..

Comment: `thisDecade = thisDecade ++;` you just need `thisDecade++;`

Comment: Also, `thisDecade = thisDecade++` is undefined behavior, as there is no sequence point between the assignment and increment. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) on why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the strings created for `thisYear` (presumably what you are using to title your buttons) are going to be off by one year because you are incrementing the `thisDecade` variable after using it to format your strings. I believe you should either move the incrementing before the NSString formatting or move it after your NSLog statement. Also, you only need to write `thisDecade++;` to increment the variable.

Comment: Thanks Patrick - that's very helpful. I'm off to see what I can make of your answer, but I sense you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is probably in the line

> ```
> thisDecade = thisDecade ++;
> ```

You should keep in mind that the in- and decrement operators (`++`, `--`) already store the new value in the variable. So this would be ok:

```
++thisDecade;
```

What you are trying to do is undefined. Take look at this, starting at slice 142: http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c

Comment: Thanks to you both. The slideshare presentation is great. I need to work through it. However, neither ++thisDecade or thisDecade++ results in different logs than in my question. Is there somewhere else I should look?